# OpenOffice.org Writer RegEx

Tags: regex, openoffice-writer

I have some badly formatted text which I am attempting to reformat using the OpenOffice.org Writer's Find/Replace functionality which supports regular expressions as defined [here](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Regular_Expressions_in_Writer).

The problem is some paragraphs have been split into two paragraphs mid-sentence. For example (using ^ to represent the start and $ to represent end of paragraph):

> ^This is a good paragraph.$
>
> ^He said: "This is a good paragraph."$
>
> ^But these$
>
> ^are two broken ones that should be merged into one.$

I was hoping to construct a regex to find any paragraphs that don't end in a `.` or `"` and merge it with the next paragraph (by replacing the end of paragraph with a space, then later I will check for any double spaces).

Doing a find for the search term `$` finds (and selects) the end of every paragraph, so it can be replaced. However `[^\.]$` finds every paragraph that doesn't end in `.` but selects the last character not the end of paragraph so I can't replace it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you want. A negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\.|")$\n
```

However, I don't know if  OOo Writers supports negative lookbehinds, so instead you can replace with a captured group.

```
Find:     ([^."])$\n
Replace:  $1
```